# Should we start a blog?

Tags: discussion

I seem to remember seeing several other sites on the SE network (including betas) having blogs that included community contributed posts about various topics relevant to the site. I think there are plenty of potential topics within brewing that could be addressed as posts. Seeing as this site tends to be a little slower with new questions (since brewing its self takes time), this might be a good way to drive some more traffic to the site.

Opinions? Potential topics? Volunteers to write?

Comment: Back in the days of yore, when we started BrewAdvice.com and thought SE was going to start charging for the service, there was a blog:

http://blog.brewadvice.com/

Comment: [bump] any other feedback on this question?

Comment: Having a blog would be great, but it requires serious dedication from at least a handful of individuals.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea, I've thought about it a bit over the last couple of months as other SE sites have began theirs. I think that we should have 5 or more posts a month in order for it to seem 'alive'.

I could contribute 6 or so blog posts a year.

There are a few other things that we may want to consider.

- Scheduling, do we want a schedule for posting (IE every Monday?) also how do we ensure that two people don't write a blog post about the same thing.
- Editing, who is in charge of copy editing (spelling/grammar)
- Technical quality control, we don't want incorrect information posted on our blog
- Posting, who is responsible for posting to the blog

I'm sure there are more, but these are a couple things that I thought of offhand.